# I'm getting an Unhandled Promise Rejection error but can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, express, massive

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const massive = require('massive');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const config = require('../config');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//massive connection string to database

massive(config.dblink).then(db => {
    app.set('db', db)

    app.get('db').seed_file().then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
});

const port = 3001;
app.listen(port, () => {console.log(`the server is listening on ${port}`)})
```

I am getting the following error:

```
(node:173676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 2): error: syntax error at or near "{"                                           
(node:173676) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will 
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I haven't been able to figure out what is wrong. I have looked at multiple different examples, but cannot see the problem. I have a `.catch` after my `seed_file` promise.

Any thoughts?

Comment: right below `console.log(res)` you have an extra `})`. Delete that and you should be good

Comment: @MarkDodds this is not the case, just the code is not well formatted

Answer (score 6):

> I'm getting an Unhandled Promise Rejection error but can't figure out
>   why

You get this warning because you have **unhandled promise rejection** :). The outer `catch()` method is not handling nested promise rejections, so two options could be:

**1)** Use **return** on your nested promise and it will be caught from the outer `catch()`:

```
massive(config.dblink).then(db => {
    app.set('db', db)
    return app.get('db').seed_file().then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    });
}).catch(err => console.log(err) });
```

**2)** Use inner `catch()` to handle differently the nested rejection:

```
massive(config.dblink).then(db => {
    app.set('db', db)
    app.get('db').seed_file().then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err) });
}).catch(err => console.log(err) });
```

**Demonstration:**

```js
function doPromise(someText, flag) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      flag ? resolve(someText) : reject(someText);
    }, 500);
  });
}

/* The following sample demostrates unhandled rejection */
doPromise('this will resolve', true).then(function(res1) {
  console.log(res1);
  doPromise('this is unhandled promise rejection', false).then(function(res2) {
    console.log(res2);
  });
});

/* The following sample demostrates handling nested promise rejection like explained in point 1) */
doPromise('1) this will resolve', true).then(function(res1) {
  console.log(res1);
  return doPromise('1) nested rejection catched from outside', false);
}).catch(err => console.log(err));


/* The following sample demostrates handling nested promise rejection like explained in point 2) */
doPromise('2) this will resolve', true).then(function(res1) {
  console.log(res1);
  doPromise('2) nested rejection catched from inside', false).catch(err => console.log(err));
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```